# JQuery Mobile popup snaps to top after closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, jquery-mobile

I'm working on an app that uses JQuery Mobile to show a popup upon tapping an image.
This image is a larger version of the tapped one.

The problem is that when I tap anywhere on the screen it snaps to the top of the page, which is annoying when you want to browse through the images.

Is this a common thing with JQuery Mobile?
I don't have any code to show besides this:

```
<div class="block">
    <a href="#BL209" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window"><img src="img/items/autorai-b/BL209.jpg" alt="block" width="100%" height="100%"></a>
    <p>BL209</p>
    <div data-role="popup" id="BL209">
        <img src="img/items/autorai-b/BL209.jpg" alt="block" width="100%" height="100%">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: popup shouldn't be wrapped in any _element_ but _page div_. In other words, popup's direct parent should be _page div_.

Comment: @Omar Any source for this? I tried putting the popup div right in the page (`data-role="page"`) but it didn't have any effect. Do I need to have all of the popup div's inside of the page or can I test this by moving only 1 and using that one?